# A dot in the air

Tags: photons, ionization-energy

I want to make a dot in our air without a vacuum. Weather it's with a laser intersecting with something else to emit a visible particle or with ionization. I want to make a small dot. What kind of laser do I need to ionize a with the least and smallest amount of energy? Or with the intersecting concept, what would be two beams I can bounce off mirrors to make a visible intersection?

Answer (score 2):

You don't see light unless light enters your eye. For example, you don't see a beam of light pointed away from you.

If there is dust floating in the air, light will reflect off it in all directions. Some will go toward your eye. You will that. This is what makes a beam of light visible.

So get a black background. Float one dust particle in the air. Shine a light on it.